# React Js GitHub Pages Problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please help me

I have been creating a single pages aplication,  a github pages using react js. All deployed was work. 
For example my site :
"https://wicaker.github.io".
In my site, have two nav links, home and about.
When a render https://wicaker.github.io , then click the navlink about,  all work. But the issues :

When a render with https://wicaker.github.io/about in search box , the pages is not found.

My index.js code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

app.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavbarMenu from './layout/Navbar';
import MyComponent from'./pages/Parallax';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import About from'./pages/About';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <BrowserRouter>
      <div >
        <NavbarMenu />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component ={MyComponent}/>
          <Route exact path='/about' component ={About}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

about.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Parallax , Col} from 'react-materialize';
import backgroundParallax from '../images/backgroundParallax.jpeg';
import Profile from '../images/profile.jpg'; 
import Skills from './Skills';
import Project from './Project';
import Contact from './Contact';
import MyFooter from './Footer';

class About extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
     <div >
      <div className="section white">
        <div className="row container">
          <Col m={12} className='center'><h2 className="header"><font face="Courier New"><b>Who is Me ?</b></font></h2></Col>
          <Col m={9}>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit aperiam est repudiandae a repellendus illum pariatur cumque quisquam, at ipsum, maxime amet excepturi perferendis distinctio non architecto obcaecati quia quas.</Col>
          <Col m={3} className='right'><img src={Profile} className="circle" alt="i-gede-wicaksana" /></Col>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Parallax imageSrc={backgroundParallax}/>
      <Skills />
      <Project />
      <Contact />
      <MyFooter />
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default About;
```

I really appreciate for the answer. 
Thank you

Comment: Can you paste your index.js code?

Comment: i have been adding my index.js code

Comment: please add App component

Comment: i have been adding my app.js and about.js code

Comment: I would guess that the problem is with github pages not being able to recognize your front-end routes. Even when using your own webserver, such as Apache, you need to tell the serve that it should route every request that it does not recognize to root and leave React handler routing. You may try adding `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` to your `BrowserRouter` component.

Comment: there isn't any issue with your routing inside the react app

this is what you're looking for https://medium.com/@Dragonza/react-router-problem-with-gh-pages-c93a5e243819

give @Ngoc Vuong a clap